# Add years to a variable date within a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have code where Im going through each row at a time and taking the 3rd column which is the date.

It echos the date in format `04-04-2017`. Each row has a different date and I wish to take 5 years from that date and put it in the new variable `dob_want2` but keep getting the error date:

```
invalid date â€˜'04-04-2017' -5 yearsâ€™
```

The file `temp9_0.txt` is in the format

```
123 5555 04-04-2017
126 1234 25-11-2014
218 0023 13-06-2002
```

and `echo "$dob_want"` outputs

```
04-04-2017
```

Its obviously not recognising `$dob_want` as a date. Any help suggestions on how I could treat this variable as a date would be much appreciated.

```bash
dob_want=$(head -1 temp9_0.txt | awk '{print $3}')
echo "$dob_want"
dob_want2=$(date  +%d-%m-%y -d "$dob_want -5 years")
echo "$dob_want2"
```

Comment: You will want to start by getting your date into a format that GNU `date` can parse. See e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).

Comment: Are you trying to subtract dates? In a character format?

Comment: For those wondering about  the `â€˜` and `â€™` I suspect they come from inappropriate terminal translation of the message "ticks" rather then from the input data (I get the same using PuTTY with Win1252 instead of UTF-8). The real issue is the `d-m-Y` (or is it `m-d-Y`) format as @Kusalananda has already pointed out.

Comment: @steeldriver I wonder if the `â€˜` and `â€™` are ticks that are included in the input data, which is wrongly encoded for the locale. (The OP including `echo "$dob_want"` as [already asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655779/add-years-to-a-variable-date-within-a-loop#comment1233412_655779) could help ascertain that.)

Comment: @roaima yeah AFAIK GNU `date` doesn't provide any flexibility about the *input* format - newer versions of `busybox date` do, as do the `dateutils` utilities ex. `dateutils.dadd -i '%d-%m-%Y' -f '%d-%m-%y' 04-04-2017 -5y`

Comment: @steeldriver oh now that's nice. It saves having to reimplement scanf() each time (or slice'n'dice the string, whatever)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have added an example of what temp9.txt looks like and the echo dob want. All dates are in in the format day/month/year e.g 27/06/2021 and I wish in the loop to take 5 years from the date so it would read 27/06/2016. I have made sure the input files are compatable with linux using tr -d '\r' <file > out.txt but this may not be sufficient for date columns

Comment: Can you post the output of `date --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the `date` utility is required in your case at all, since you want to perform a rather simple operation on the year only (substracting 5 years would just mean decrement the `yyyy` part of `dd-mm-yyyy` by 5).

In this case, the following `awk` program will modify the dates in the third column of your input file:

```
~$ awk -v offs=-5 '{split($3,df,"-"); printf "%02d-%02d-%04d\n",df[1],df[2],df[3]+offs}' temp9_0.txt 
04-04-2012
25-11-2009
13-06-1997
```

by adding the offset specified via as variable `offs` to the 3rd (dash-separated) sub-field of the 3rd column, and printing the modified subfield values via `printf`. It does so by using the `split` command to split the 3rd column at the `-` into the array `df` (*date fields*).

To apply this to a specific line rather than all, and assuming there are no empty lines, you can specify an additional variable `line` and make the program selective to only that line by evaluating `FNR`, `awk`s automatic per-file line-counter:

```
awk -v line=3 -v offs=-5 'FNR==line {split($3,df,"-"); printf "%02d-%02d-%04d",df[1],df[2],df[3]+offs}' temp9_0.txt
```

This output could then be caught in a shell variable via command substitution, as in

```
dob_want2=$(awk -v line=3 .....)
```

Comment: Thank you- this worked as a work around!